# How can I read a file in cat << EOF >

Tags: linux, shell, eof, cat

I would like to print a file in cat << EOF>. e.g.

```
$cat file
ad3
c43
34e
se3
we3
```

My script is:

```
$cat run.sh
cat << EOF > test.sh
#!/bin/bash
some commands
cat file #I would like to print the content of the file here
some commands
EOF
```

I can't able to print as desire with `./run.sh`

Desire output

```
$cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
some commands
ad3
c43
34e
se3
we3
some commands
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use backticks, or write the file in chunks:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<OMG >zfile
ad3
c43
34e
se3
we3
OMG

# Method1 : backticks

cat << EOF > test.sh
#!/bin/bash
some commands1
`cat zfile`
some commands2
EOF

# Method2: append

cat << EOF1 > test2.sh
#!/bin/bash
some commands1
EOF1

cat zfile >> test2.sh

cat << EOF2 >> test2.sh
some commands2
EOF2
```

Comment: Excellent.. I use method 2, which looks so manual... But looking for the method like method 1... Thanks

Comment: There is no point recommending backticks; they are obsolete and only need to be recognized in old legacy code, not used in new code.

Comment: Use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: Backticks are not obsolete, they are a Bourne shell feature still supported by bash.

Comment: "Obsolete" does not mean "unsupported".

Answer (score 3):

You could use a compound command:

```
{ cat << EOF ; cat file ; cat << EOF2; } > test.sh
> start
> EOF
> more
> EOF2
```

That gives:

```
start
ad3
c43
34e
se3
we3
more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for something like that?

```sh
cat > test.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
some commands
ad3
c43
34e
se3
we3
some commands
EOF
```